# Regex match any link ending by digit except 404 and 410

Tags: regex, .htaccess

Still new to Regex, I'd like to know how do you do that.

**The idea is to match any link which end with /23.../ (number) but not `/410/` and `/404/`**

The purpose is to put it in an .htacces so I can redirect old pages to 410.

Every single old pages is in the shape of http://www.blabla.com/something/2/
http://www.blabla.com/something/3/ etc ...

So I've done this Regex which is working except it is including 404 and 410 too and that I can't allowed.

`^(.*?)\/\d+$` https://regex101.com/r/tD2sX0/2

I then tough of this one but this is not working properly since it does not capture my URL and I'm not sure why.

`^(.*?(404|410))\/\d+$` https://regex101.com/r/tD2sX0/4

A bit of help would be gladly accepted.

Comment: Try [`^(.*?)\/(?!(?:404|410)$)\d+$`](https://regex101.com/r/tD2sX0/5).

Comment: @stribizhev first shot, seems to work well, thank you !

Comment: If you might have `/` at the end, you can also use `^(.*?)\/(?!(?:404|410)$)\d+\/?$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add exceptions inside a negative look-ahead:

```
^(.*?)\/(?!(?:404|410)$)\d+$
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tD2sX0/5)

The look-ahead applies a restriction on the `\d+` (=*1 or more digits*) so that the digit sequence cannot be `404` or `410`.

I am using a non-capturing group so as to keep the back-reference list clean. The `$` end of string anchor is very important in the look-ahead since it only limits the numbers excluded to exactly `404` and `410` (otherwise, it would also exclude `41004`).

Comment: Well, I won't have it :) Acc. to the current requirements, it should pass.